# Understanding complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I need to show that

$$\left | \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik}\right | $$ is bounded

Now I am given that $$ \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} = e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}$$

But have little idea of how to proceed further and find some upper bound for this. In particular, I know I could say there is some real number out there that is an upper bound for this, but I was hoping to find the $\sup$ of this if possible.

How would I proceed?

Comment: Use Euler's formula.

Comment: @Nameless How so?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Decompose the expression into real and imaginary parts and show the each is bounded.

Comment: I do not know precisely what you mean by this.

That expression seems as simplified as it can get, and there is no instance of a real number in it?

Answer (score 1):

Take modulus to $\displaystyle e^i\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}$ and use the triangle inequality to conclude.

Also remember that $|e^{ix}|=1, \  \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: So I tried this:

$| e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1} | \leq |e^i| |\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^{i-1}} = |\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}| = \frac{ | e^{in}-1|}{|e^i -1|}$

Have I utilised this inequality wrong, or should I keep going?

Comment: The first step is an equality and also you still not use the triangle inequality.

The idea is to note that $|e^i\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}|\leq |e^i|\frac{|e^{in}|+|1|}{|e^i-1|}$

Comment: My main concern was with the denominator term, since you send $| e^{in} | = 1 \forall n$

Would we not be dividing by $0$ in that instance?

Comment: The only form that $z-w=0$ is that $z=w$. The fact that $|z|=|w|$ only said that $z$ and $w$ live in the same circumference with respect to the origin, but it doesn't mean that they are the same complex number. This is exactly what happen here.
Exercise: make a picture of $e^i$ and $1$ in the complex plane and geometrically calculates the modulus $|e^i-1|$.